Induced map on stalks is bijective for all $x\in X$ if and only if the morphism of presheaf is bijective for any open subset
Claim:Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathscr{F},\mathscr{G}$ be two presheaves on $X$. Let $\varphi:\mathscr{F}\rightarrow \mathscr{G}$ be a morphism of presheaves. If $\mathscr{F},\mathscr{G}$ are both sheaves, then 
the induced maps on stalks $\varphi_x:\mathscr{F}_x\rightarrow \mathscr{G}_x$ is bijective for all $x\in X$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\varphi(U):\mathscr{F}(U)\rightarrow \mathscr{G}(U)$ is bijective for all $U\subset X$ open.

Question: I am mainly confused about the surjectivity of the only if direction. That is, assume $U\subset X$ open then for each $t\in \mathscr{G}(U)$ we need to find some $s\in \mathscr{F}(U)$ such that $\varphi(s)=t$. The author claims for each $x\in U$ we can find an open neighbourhood $U^x$ of $x$ in $U$ and $s^x\in \mathscr{F}(U^x)$ such that $(\varphi_{U^x}(s^x))_x=t_x$, where $(\varphi_{U^x}(s^x))_x,t_x$ denote the image of $\varphi_{U^x}(s^x)$ and $t$ under the map $\mathscr{F}(U)\rightarrow \mathscr{F}_x$ respectively. I don not know why this is true? Why it is not necessarily surjective for a larger open nbhd then after some suitable shrinking we can assume on a small open nbhd of $x$ the corresponding morphism between two sheaves is surjective.
It is the second proposition in page 52 of Ulrich Görtz and Torsten Wedhorn's Algebraic Geometry I:Schemes.

Elements of $\mathscr{F}_x$ are equivalence classes of pairs $(U,s)$ where $U$ is an open set containing $x$, and $s \in \mathscr{F}(U)$. Two pairs $(U_1,s_1)$ and $(U_2,s_2)$ are equivalent if there is an open set $V$ of $x$ such that $V \subseteq U_1 \cap U_2$ and $s_1|V = s_2|V$.
The map $\varphi_x:\mathscr{F}_x\rightarrow \mathscr{G}_x$ is surjective. Hence, there is an element $(U_x, s^x)$ in $\mathscr{F}_x$, where $U_x$ is an open set containing $x$ and $s^x \in \mathscr{F}(U_x)$ such that $\varphi_x((U_x,s^x)) = (U,t)$.
By definition of the map $\varphi_x$, this means that $(U_x,\varphi_{U_x}(s^x)) = (U,t)$.
